# How to check what style a button has applied to it NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles, block

in developer tools I can see my button:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$MapUserControl$MapDefPage$CreateEditLayerPage$addAttribute" value="Add Attribute" id="ctl00_MainContent_MapUserControl_MapDefPage_CreateEditLayerPage_addAttribute" title="Click to add a new attribute to the layer" class="edit green btn spaceRight" style="float: right; display: block;">
```

You can see at the end the style has a DISPLAY of BLOCK.

But when I try to test this in the console:

```
$('addAttribute').css("display") == "block"
false
```

I get a return of FALSE, when I can see it should be TRUE. Why is this?
Basically I want to check if my button is hidden or visible so I can perform a task depending on which.
Have also tried

```
$('addAttribute').is(":visible"); 
false
```

But returns false as well. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `addAtribute` is not an id and not a class or other in your input. Is that normal ?

Comment: What is your selector? there is no object as `<addAttribute />`, to select class use `.class`, id - `#id`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you use wrong selector. You are using like

```
$('addAttribute').css("display") == "block"
```

but there is not any tag like `addAttribute`. You can check like

```
$('.edit.green.btn.spaceRight').css("display") == "block"
```

Also you can check with your input's id

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert($(':input.btn').css("display") == "block")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$MapUserControl$MapDefPage$CreateEditLayerPage$addAttribute" value="Add Attribute" id="ctl00_MainContent_MapUserControl_MapDefPage_CreateEditLayerPage_addAttribute" title="Click to add a new attribute to the layer" class="edit green btn spaceRight" style="float: right; display: block;">
```

Use `:input` selector to select the input with class to be more accurate

Comment: @rushil on OP nothing was mention of those things but he can add class if he wants.

Comment: now the ans is preferable after you edited... adding one more attribute .btn might work

Answer (score 0):

```js
if($('.edit.green.btn.spaceRight').css("display") == "block"){
  alert('yes');
}else{
  alert('no');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$MapUserControl$MapDefPage$CreateEditLayerPage$addAttribute" value="Add Attribute" id="ctl00_MainContent_MapUserControl_MapDefPage_CreateEditLayerPage_addAttribute" title="Click to add a new attribute to the layer" class="edit green btn spaceRight" style="float: right; display: block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find based on `input` element and it's `id` as follows,

In your current code the selector you are referring to `addAttribute` is incorrect.

```js
if ($('input#ctl00_MainContent_MapUserControl_MapDefPage_CreateEditLayerPage_addAttribute').css("display") == "block") {
  alert("Detected");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$MapUserControl$MapDefPage$CreateEditLayerPage$addAttribute" value="Add Attribute" id="ctl00_MainContent_MapUserControl_MapDefPage_CreateEditLayerPage_addAttribute" title="Click to add a new attribute to the layer"
class="edit green btn spaceRight" style="float: right; display: block;">
```